# Django: download does not start after returnig a file from view

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Having gathered info from various Stack Overflow threads, I have came up with the following view function in Django to return a text file through HttpResponse object:

```
def serve_file(request):
    filepath = sampler_settings.ZIP_PATH + '/test_file'
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test_file"'
    return response
```

The function is called from the front-end like this:

```
function serve_file() {
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/serve_file'
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => console.log(text))
}
```

However, the only thing that happens is that the file contents get printed in the browser console, but the download does not start: there is no prompt or anything.

This is on development server on Ubuntu and Firefox.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried `document.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/serve_file";`?  (you need to let the browser handle the file if you want it to save it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that http request via ajax is different from normal request from browser. Ajax gives you response in JavaScript. So you have to request file from browser (using `window.location`) natively or make a download via JavaScript like this.

```
function serve_file() {
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/serve_file'
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {

          const blob = new Blob(text, {type: 'application/forced-download'});
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.download = "file_name";
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
    })
}
```